# Show a DIV before 48hours of ACF DateTimePicker field and hide after 24hours of the same ACF DateTimePicker field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, datetimepicker

I'm trying to show an ACF field before 48hours of a specified ACF DateTimePicker and want to hide it after 24 hours, the fields are always showing, and not getting hidden after 24 hours, could you please assist me what am I doing wrong, below is my code

```
    <?php //show match predictions only of it has a value and in between the specified date and time 
    $showPredictionTime = date("d/m/Y, g:i a", strtotime('+54 hours', time()));
     $hidepredictionTime = date("d/m/Y, g:i a", strtotime('+78 hours', time()));
    $matchStartTime = get_sub_field('match_time'); 
      if (get_sub_field('match_predictions_url') && $showPredictionTime >= $matchStartTime && $matchStartTime <= $hidepredictionTime ) { ?>
     <div class="elementor-button-wrapper"> 
<a href="<?php the_sub_field('match_predictions_url'); ?>" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-xs" role="button"> 
<span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
<span class="elementor-button-text">Predictions</span>
</span> 
    </a> 
    </div>
    <?php }  
    ?>
```

Comment: What is the return value of "match_time"? Is it a full date object?

Comment: Also, the window of time you have created in your variables is not a 72 hour window, which from the description sounds like how long you want it to show

Comment: hi @JamesHamann yes I'm getting the "match_time" in the format of "d/m/Y, g:i a"
Yes I might have gone wrong with hours calculation based on my timezone, That I can adjust, the main issue is to show "Predictions" before 48 hours and hide after 24hours and only if it has value entered in that field